# Setting an "Event Handler" on a Form's "GridView" loaded from an assembly by reflection in C#

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, event-handling

Setting an **"EventHandler"** on a Form's "DataGridView" loaded from an assembly by reflection, causes to disable all previous **Event Handler** defined on **"DataGridView"** although EventHandlers are not the same

I use code below to load an assembly as a 'Form'

```
string FullName = ApplicationPath + @"\DLL\" + DllName + ".dll";
System.Reflection.Assembly assmbly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(FullName);
Type[] contr = assmbly.GetTypes();

if (contr[0].BaseType.FullName == ("System.Windows.Forms.Form"))
{
   System.Windows.Forms.Form frm = assmbly.CreateInstance(contr[0].FullName) as Form;
   frm.Show();
}
```

And then I use code below to set an "Event Handler" on a Form's "DataGridView" loaded from an assembly

```
foreach (Control ThisControl in ThisView.Controls) // ThisView is the same Form loaded from an assembly
{
  if (ThisControl.GetType().ToString().Trim() == "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView")
  {
     DataGridView ThisGrid = (DataGridView)ThisControl;
     ThisGrid.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(ThisGrid_MouseDown);
  }
}
```

what's wrong?
thanks All...

Comment: This code doesn't disable any event handlers. Could you post complete sample, which reproduces the problem? Besides, don't test for base class using type name, use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` method.

Comment: Hey really Thanks...You are exactly right dear Dannis...All times I thought this problem is because of creating events dynamically...You know what was happenning?! I have dragdrop event too and I had __DoDragDrop(-1, DragDropEffects.Copy);__ method in the 'MouseDown' event....this method causes to conflict with previous Events . I have to use this method by defining a condition.you are also right about using  __Type.IsAssignableFrom__ I'll do it .Thanks anyway :D